# Clang-format is giving error

Tags: ubuntu, vim, clang, llvm, clang-format

I've configured `.vimrc` file for using `clang-format-3.5.py` in gvim on ubuntu.
Now pressing `Ctrl+k` getting some error like

```
Formatting failed: usable .clang-format, using LLVM Style (total 0 errors)
```

And it works for most of the cases, but when line is length increases more than 80 lines it does not break into next line.

How can I make changes to use certain particular style with clang.

Comment: I have the same error, but it seems to work. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either put a file name .clang-format into your project's directory (or any parent directory) or explicitly alter clang-format-3.5.py and hard-code a style there.

For some help on generating a .clang-format file, see here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html